# git status does not ignore submodules

Tags: git

Even though I set `git config --global diff.ignoreSubmodules` `git status` does not ignore changes in submodules and still shows them as modified content. My git version is 2.20.1.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong diff.ignoreSubmodules is buggy and is ignored if submodule..ignore is set.

You need to use the command line option --ignore-submodules=all instead or change the ignore setting for the module as they are the only mechanisms that work.